# Python MongoDB and Bastion Server

Tags: javascript, python, bastion

I have to execute javascript command on MongoDB Server. To access MongoDB server I need to login first to Bastion Server. I wrote python script to connect to bastion server

I am getting below error in python script which is trying to connect to bastion server:   File "retTest.py", line 20, in 
ssh_client.connect(hostname=bastion_host, username=bastion_username, key_filename=bastion_private_key)
File "/site/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 386, in connect
sock.connect(addr)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

This code should execute without any error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.